# Plot multiple columns side by side

Tags: pandas, plot, bar-chart

I have the dataframe below.

```
       111_a  111_b  222_a  222_b  333_a  333_b
row_1  1.0    2.0    1.5    2.5    1.0    2.5
row_2  1.0    2.0    1.5    2.5    1.0    2.5
row_3  1.0    2.0    1.5    2.5    1.0    2.5
```

I'm trying to plot a bar chart such that column `*_a` are together, and `*_b` are together. I would also be plotting each row (`row_1`, `row_2`, etc) in separate tables.

What I'm trying to get is this:

[image]

where in my case,

```
Asia.SUV = 111_a, Europe.SUV = 222_a, USA.SUV = 333_a
Asia.Sedan = 111_b, Europe.Sedan = 222_b, USA.Sedan = 333_b
```

I would rename the "Type". How can I plot this? It would also be a bonus if I can plot each row in separate tables with just a command, instead of manually plotting each row.

Comment: the output you expect is not fully clear as you have a difference between the dataset and the image, can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `df` the dataframe, you can use:

```
ax = df.T.rename_axis(columns='Origin', index='Type').plot.bar()
ax.set_ylabel('Frequency')
```

output:

[image: grouped bar plot]

Comment: I'm trying to plot row_1, row_2 and row_3 on 3 separate tables. Then 111_a, 222_a and 333_a would be together, 111_b, 222_b and 333_b would be together, like the blue, orange and green bars you have. There would only be 2 "types".